# How to bind data from Dictionary to xaml and use selected object

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

### CategoriesView.xaml

```
<local:AllViewBase x:Class="Test.View.Tab.CategoriesView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test.View.Abstract"
             mc:Ignorable="d">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Content/Style/MainWindowDictionary.xaml"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=dcCategory}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Category,Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                            <Button Content="Add Value" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.AddValue, RelativeSource= {RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Key}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Value}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid> 
</local:AllViewBase>
```

### CategoriesViewModel.cs

```
namespace Test.ViewModel.Tab
{
    public class CategoriesViewModel : AllViewModel<CategoryValueAllView>
    {
        private BaseCommand _AddValue;

        private Category _Category;
        public Category Category
        {
            get
            {
                return _Category;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_Category != value)
                {
                    _Category = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(() => Category);
                }
            }
        }

        private Dictionary<Category, List<string>> _dcCategory;
        public Dictionary<Category, List<string>> dcCategory
        {
            get
            {
                if (_dcCategory == null) LoadDictionary();
                return _dcCategory;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_dcCategory != value)
                {
                    _dcCategory = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(() => dcCategory);
                }
            }
        }

        public ICommand AddValue
        {
            get
            {
                if (_AddValue == null)
                {
                    _AddValue = new BaseCommand(() => Messenger.Default.Send(CategoryValueCode.AddValue + "," + Category.CategoryId));
                }
                return _AddValue;
            }
        }

        public void LoadDictionary()
        {
            dcCategory = (from k in db.Category join w in db.CategoryVal on k.CategoryId equals w.CategoryId select new CategoryValueAllView { Category = w.Category, Val = w.Val }).GroupBy(x => x.Category).ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.Select(obj => obj.Val).ToList());
        }
    }
}
```

My goals are:

- `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Key}"/>` show Category.Name. I don't
  know how to use Key like an object and use property Name
- when I push the button 'Add Value' I want to set 'CategoryId' in 'Category' object and sent it throught 'AddValue' Command by
  Messenger

Earlier I used the string category.name instead of the category object for dictionary key. Then `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Key}"/>` showing correct name, but after all I was unable to pass the 'category.name' to the 'AddValue' command after click button to get id by name and set data by Messenger.

Getting id by the name is acceptable too, the Category object as a key is not required

in spite of everything I would like to learn it, but I can not stand an example which has show such a problem

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to bind Key.Name to the TextBlock?

Comment: yes - it works, ahh I was convinced that I tried that already :)
the question of the button action remained

Comment: Do you mean you wish to send CategoryId as a CommandParameter?

Comment: Yes, I am currently trying to write something like this (refering to hints from Key.Name):
<ListBox ItemsSource = "{Binding Path = dcCategory}" SelectedValuePath = "{Binding Path = Key.CategoryId}" SelectedValue = "{Binding Path = Key.CategoryId, Mode = TwoWay}">
but without results

Comment: It should be: <ListBox ItemsSource = "{Binding Path = dcCategory}" SelectedValuePath = "CategoryId" SelectedValue = "{Binding Path = SelectedCategoryId, Mode = TwoWay}">. Here SelectedCategoryId should be a property on your viewmodel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use Key.Name for binding to TextBlock
2. For binding to the listbox you have two ways:

-Use SelectedItem. You already have a property "Category" in your viewmodel. Bind that property to the listbox selected item. You can then use Category.CategoryID in your AddValue command.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource = "{Binding Path = dcCategory}" SelectedItem = "{Binding Path = Category, Mode = TwoWay}">
```

-Use SelectedValue. SelectedCategoryId should be a property on the viewmodel. You can then directly use this property inside your AddValue command.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource = "{Binding Path = dcCategory}" SelectedValuePath = "CategoryId" SelectedValue = "{Binding Path = SelectedCategoryId, Mode = TwoWay}">
```

Comment: <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=dcCategory}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Category,Mode=TwoWay}"> - dosent work (Id = 0), and 

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=dcCategory}" SelectedValuePath="{Binding Path=CategoryId}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Id,Mode=TwoWay}"> - dosent work too (Category object is null)

Comment: The second option will never have category set. But, the first option should work if your item source has the correct values.

Comment: Thank you, without your help I did not get this code worked: **<ListBox ItemsSource = "{Binding Path = dcCategory}" SelectedValuePath = "Key" SelectedValue = "{Binding Path = Category, Mode = TwoWay}">**